# Android Retrofit request how to get retrofit response in main Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, nullpointerexception, retrofit

I use retrofit to get the response correctly, then I pass the response to an object in the response body, while it fails to get the object in UI thread, there is a NullPointerException Error, I think it's the problem of the asynchronous request, how can I avoid this problem?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    util = new Util(this);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            util.login("sdjfl@gmail.com", "sdjflsdkf");

            // There is a NullPointerException? How Can I
            // use this methond correctly in this way?
            Log.d("user", util.getUserInfo().toString());
        }
    });
}

public class Util {
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
        return userInfo;
    }

    public void login(final String email, final String password) {
        Call<UserInfo> loginCall = apiInterface.login(email, password);
        loginCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserInfo> call, Response<UserInfo> response) {
                userInfo = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserInfo> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line inside the `onResponse()`

```
Log.d("user", util.getUserInfo().toString());
```

You are getting the user info object too realy, it's null at the point you are trying to access it

Like that

```
public class Util {
    public interface Callback {
        void onResponse(UserInfo info);
    }
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
        return userInfo;
    }

    public void login(final String email, final String password, final Callback callback) {
        Call<UserInfo> loginCall = apiInterface.login(email, password);
        loginCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserInfo> call, Response<UserInfo> response) {
                userInfo = response.body();
                callback.onResponse(userInfo);
                Log.d("user", userInfo.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserInfo> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

And here's how you use it

```
Util.login("email", "password", new Util.Callback() {
   void onResponse(User info) {
       // Update UI
   }
});
```

Please be aware that this callback can leak memory, make sure to clean it if you leave your current activity/fragment.

Comment: yeah, but I just want to get the return value in clickListener, otherwise I can't get it if I move it to the response block

Comment: But you cannot get it in the click listener, you listener onClick() method will finish execution long before you network call come back with response, what do you want to do with the response? update UI?

Comment: I just want to get the response immediately, because in the next step I will use the return value to make another request

Comment: Network requests take time, you can NOT get it immediately, if you to execute another request, do it on onResponse of the first one.

Comment: but I still want to make a copy of this response and update the UI

Comment: @JinmingShi Updated the asnwer, take a look

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm little confused about the interface, I don't know how it could solve this problem ,as I followed your code, there is some compile error

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the return type of the interface method, I added a usage example

Comment: it works, as you mentioned it will leak the memory, how could I clean it like you said

Comment: There are multiple ways, you can for example use WeakReference to hold the Callback instance

Comment: ok, thank you very much for your great help!!!